# How to create clickable elements displayed on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm displaying svg elements - let's named them tags - on mouseover events onto graph nodes. Show/hide of those is pretty satisfying, although possibly improved. However, I would like the elements that are displayed on mouseover to be clickable.

Currently, mouseover events on tags are not captured. If I disable the on mouseout event which wipe tags out, events on tags are properly captured, but obviously tags remain forever.

Is there a way for the tags to be clickable and wiped out on mouse out events on parent? I thought about adding 1s delay before removing tags but neither know how to do it nor if it's the right thing to do.

The code below shows a function example - fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/pducrot/4eyb81kx/

```
// graph size
var width = 400;
var height = 400;

var nodes = [{name: 'A'}, {name: 'B'}, {name: 'C'}, {name: 'D'}];
var edges = [{source: 'A', target: 'B'}, {source: 'B', target: 'C'}, {source: 'C', target: 'A'}, {source: 'C', target: 'D'}];
var tags = [10, 35, 56, 9];

var nodeMap = {};
nodes.forEach(function (x) {nodeMap[x.name] = x;});
var links = edges.map(function (x) {
    return {source: nodeMap[x.source], target: nodeMap[x.target], value: 1};
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.attr("pointer-events", "all")
.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
.append('g');

var force = d3.layout.force()
.gravity(.25)
.distance(140)
.charge(-3500)
.size([width, height]);

var stdDragStart = force.drag().on("dragstart.force");
force.drag()
.on("dragstart", function (d) {
//prevent dragging on the nodes from dragging the canvas
d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
stdDragStart.call(this, d);
});

force.nodes(nodes)
.links(links)
.friction(0.8)
.start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
.data(links)
.enter().append("line")
.attr("class", "link");

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(nodes)
.enter().append("svg:g")
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("id", function (d) {
return d.name
})
.on("dblclick", dblclick)
.on("mouseover", function (d) {
drawTags(tags, d.name);
})
.on("mouseout", function (d) {
d3.select("#" + d.name).selectAll(".tool").remove();
})
.call(force.drag);

node.append("circle")
.attr("class", "circle")
.attr("r", 40);

d3.selectAll(node);

// display name in nodes if node structure
node.append("text")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.text(function (d) {
return d.name;
});

force.on("tick", function () {
link.attr("x1", function (d) {return d.source.x;})
    .attr("y1", function (d) {return d.source.y;})
    .attr("x2", function (d) {return d.target.x;})
    .attr("y2", function (d) {return d.target.y;});
node.attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });
});

// redraw after zooming
function redraw() {
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

function dblclick(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
}

function dragstart(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}

function drawTags(tags, onto) {

    var rScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(tags)
    .rangeBands([-Math.PI, Math.PI]);

    var local = d3.select("#" + onto).selectAll(".tool")
    .data(tags)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("pointer-events", "all")
    .attr("class", "tool")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    var x = Math.sin(rScale(d)) * 40;
    var y = Math.cos(rScale(d)) * 40;
    return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    })
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {
    alert("mouse over tag " + d);
    });
    local.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .attr("r", 15);

    local.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: The "right thing to do" depends entirely on your application and we can't really tell you what to do. Is it reasonable in your application to give users 1s to click on something in the tooltip? Is the parent element large enough to give the expected behaviour? You could also hide the tooltip only when an element that causes another tooltip to appear is hovered.

Comment: Indeed. I guess my preferred solution would be to extend the mouseover region to tag circles instead of the 1s delay. As you may see on the image I juste added, tags are dynamically obtained from neo4j using ajax, I'd like display addition information for a specific tag on click or mouse over. One idea could also to bring the main node to the front, and only keep the tag th user moves his mouse over from the main node.

Comment: The fiddle does not work for me.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't have access to it or that the code is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial answer is to add delay before removing tags, as proposed above. This can be done on the node variable with:

```
.on("mouseout", function(d) {
    d3.select("#"+d.name).selectAll(".tool")
    .transition()
    .delay(800)
    .remove();
})
```

It's also better to reduce the overlap between tags and parent node (in drawTags) because mouseover is on the parent node only, tags are considered out.

```
var x = Math.sin(rScale(d))*50; // vs. 40px previously
var y = Math.cos(rScale(d))*50;
```

Change the mouseover event on tags to a click event and make tags and text only receive click pointer-events with .attr("pointer-events", "click")

```
.on("click", function(d) { alert(d); });
```